# in_array not working with my array in foreach

Tags: php

I want to create a small script to get every mail with specifics domain name

Here is my code

```
// $_POST
$email_list_explode = explode("\n",$_POST['email_list']);
$ndd_accepted = explode(",",$_POST['ndd']);

// ARRAY OF GOOD EMAIL
$email_good = array();

foreach ($email_list_explode as $email_list_result){

  // GETTING EMAIL DOMAIN
  $domain_name = substr(strrchr($email_list_result, "@"), 1);
  
  // CHECK IF THE EMAIL DOMAIN IS IN THE ARRAY OF ACCEPTED DOMAIN NAME
  if (in_array($domain_name, $ndd_accepted)){

    // PUSHING GOOD EMAIL IN THE ARRAY OF GOOD EMAIL
    array_push($email_good, $email_list_result);
  }
}
  
// PRINTING ARRAY OF GOOD EMAIL      
print_r($email_good);
```

Example of $_POST

```
$_POST['email_list'] = test@orange.fr
                       test2@sfr.fr
$_POST['ndd'] = gmail.com,orange.fr;
```

My $email_good array should be test@orange.fr

Comment: So, `var_dump($domain_name, $ndd_accepted)` and check what is in these variables.

Comment: in_array does work as expected. You need to filter out everything after @ and then check with in_array.

Comment: $domain_name = substr(strrchr($email_list_result, "@"), 1); that already filter everything after @ ...

Comment: string(10) "orange.fr " array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "gmail.com" [1]=> string(9) "orange.fr" } string(6) "sfr.fr" array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "gmail.com" [1]=> string(9) "orange.fr" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is in explode with \n you must explode with PHP_EOL like this

```
<?php
$_POST['email_list'] = "test@orange.fr
test2@sfr.fr";
$_POST['ndd'] = "gmail.com,orange.fr";

$email_list_explode = explode(PHP_EOL,$_POST['email_list']);
$ndd_accepted = explode(",",$_POST['ndd']);
// ARRAY OF GOOD EMAIL
$email_good = array();
foreach ($email_list_explode as $email_list_result){

  // GETTING EMAIL DOMAIN
$domain_name = explode("@",$email_list_result)[1];

// CHECK IF THE EMAIL DOMAIN IS IN THE ARRAY OF ACCEPTED DOMAIN NAME
  if (in_array($domain_name, $ndd_accepted,true)){

// PUSHING GOOD EMAIL IN THE ARRAY OF GOOD EMAIL
    array_push($email_good, $email_list_result);
  }
}

// PRINTING ARRAY OF GOOD EMAIL      
print_r($email_good);


?>
```

Comment: thanks you! was PHP_EOL :)

Comment: yes . good luck